# OCaml - Signatures, Modules and Types

Tags: ocaml

I have a basic question about types in signatures. If I have two ocaml files like:

istr.ml

```
type t = int

let get_string f v = f v
```

and fstr.ml

```
type t = float

let get_string f v = f v
```

and a signature

stri.mli

```
module type STR =
  sig

    type t

    val get_string: (t -> string) -> t -> string

  end
```

What is the type t in the above signature? Is it polymorphic?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it is an abstract type that hides the implementation and prevents the user to use it directly. see [module system](http://caml.inria.fr/pub/docs/u3-ocaml/ocaml-modules.html) or [RWO](https://realworldocaml.org/v1/en/html/files-modules-and-programs.html)
But I am not sure that your current examples will work as your code examples does not seem to be in modules.

Comment: I have read both the links you provided but I'm still having problems figuring out how types, abstract types, signatures and modules/functors come together for a final product.

Comment: in the RWO link I have given, the example is quite clear IMHO (the freq & counter example) how to hide some specific implementation. For the functor the corresponding chapter is also quite exhaustive (although I did not catch it on first reading...). May be you should explain in more detail your example (a bit difficult for me to cacth the use case you are targetting)

Comment: I guess its time to spend some serious time with those links and a code editor to see if I can figure out how it all comes together. I think one of the major hurdles is abstract types..

Comment: it seems that what you are looking for is to parametrize a module (either to manipulate int or float) - but you are not aiming to hide the implementation. Functor is the way to parametrize.